# d3 v4 + react + ES6: How to create axis programmatically?

Tags: d3.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to get my head around d3 in its current version 4. Specifically: I a trying to create the x axis for a simple line chart in react and es6.

I have seen the examples of Mike Bostock and how he does it:

```
svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "axis axis--x")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
.call(d3.axisBottom(x));
```

But that is neither react nor ES6.

On another site I have seen the following variant:

```
renderAxis() {
  var node  = this.refs.axis;
  var axis = d3.svg.axis().orient(this.props.orient).ticks(5).scale(this.props.scale);
  d3.select(node).call(axis);
}

render() {
  return <g className="axis" ref="axis" transform={this.props.translate}></g>
}
```

This is react and ES6 but not d3 in version 4.

I could try to adopt the version 3 code to version 4 of d3 but: The d3.select bothers me extremely. I don't want to make DOM-calls when I am using react (or some other library within, like d3). React should be used to render into the DOM in the most efficient way, not to get me DOM nodes.

So, my question is:
What is the react-way to create me a simple x axis? Or, if there is yet not such an answer: What is the react way to adopt the quoted code of Mike Bostock?

Comment: If you want d3 to render the axis then you have to do it the way your 2nd examples shows — by having react render the axis `<g>` and then after it reconciles the DOM calling `renderAxis()` from `componentDidUpdate`. It's understandable why you wouldn't like that approach, but it's not the wrong approach per se; this scenario is probably the main reason why `componentDidUpdate` exists. If you prefer not to do it then you must write your own JSX that creates, positions and styles the DOM elements that d3 axis would have created.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using React then you are pretty much giving control of how the DOM works to React because of it's internal workings. React will render your components inside a virtual DOM tree and then figure out the difference between the DOM tree in the page were you inserted the root component and the former. It will apply the difference between the two trees so that the tree in the page will look like the virtual one.

Mixing d3 and React requires a bit of a trick. All the elements you use d3 for (nodes or attributes) should not be owned by React. Otherwise weird stuff happens. Let's say your `transform` attribute for the `g.axis` node is set by d3, that implies that you don't render it in React. You let your d3 logic have exclusive ownership of it.

Now comes the next step. If you want to use other tools to describe DOM nodes then you got to put that logic inside [`componentWillMount` and `componentDidUpdate`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html). Basically you only render the `g` element inside the `render()` method of React and then inside those two React lifecycle handles you can change the attributes of the `g` element and what's inside.

I will point you towards this [post that goes a bit more in detail about the hows](http://nicolashery.com/integrating-d3js-visualizations-in-a-react-app/), but I would also like to give my two cents. From my perspective and experience with these two it is best to only use d3 for it's helper functions (generic math functions). Let the rendering logic (DOM composition) be done purely in React even though there's code duplication that arises. It is way easier to maintain code that is consistent and that doesn't have two different approaches to rendering mixed together.

TL;DR; Either give attributes or nodes ownership to either React or d3 for them to work together; or my recommendation, make your own axis component in React that outputs the same DOM elements as the d3 one (or different if you desire other functionality or style) and don't use d3 for rendering.

Hope I helped.

Comment: A absolutely agree about having DOM manipulations done solely by react and about using d3 for math stuff only (when used with react). I guess I will search the web some more in order to find a good example of how to use d3 solely as a math library.

Comment: Ok, I guess this should be the right answer. I have done some coding and this works suprisingly well. One should not mix d3 renderings and react renderings - react can do all of it and d3 will be there for all the calculations. Thanks :)

Comment: Answer does not really provide a solution. Search of the linked article does not return the word "axis" once

Comment: @CodeWhisperer His question was how to mix React and D3. I answered generically on best practices that still apply. I explained how to use his own d3 snippet inside his component. You're on the wrong website for copy paste code.

Comment: @AlexandruB, no, the question was "How to create axis programatically"

Comment: @CodeWhisperer From my perspective my question was answered fully. It has been pointed out that my initial thought of the task was misdirected and AlexandruB has provided enough to find my way through further research of my own.

Comment: @hurrtz Thank you. That was my initial intention as well. Providing you with the understanding of React's inner engine (at least on the surface) and how to mix an external lib, would allow you to decide on the implementation details yourself and you would no longer be blocked by this issue.

Answer (score 9):

After a couple years of trying to figure out d3 in React, this is the best way my team and I have found of doing axes:

```
const Axis = props => {
    const axisRef = axis => {
        axis && props.axisCreator(select(axis));
    };

    return <g className={props.className} ref={axisRef} />;
};
```

**Notes**

- `axisCreator` is the function returned by [`axisBottom`](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis#axisBottom), `axisLeft`, etc.  It is created outside the component to expose to the user the full power of the d3-axis library.
- `className` allows the user to style the axis however he or she wants.
- This example uses refs, which [the React docs caution against](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#dont-overuse-refs), but it uses refs to integrate with a third-party DOM library, which is [one of the reasons to use refs that the React docs call out specifically](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#when-to-use-refs).
- It is understandable that using d3's `select` bothers you, but it's required if you want to let d3 manipulate the DOM, and if you don't let d3 manipulate the DOM, you lose out on all the functionality of d3 (which is an [incredibly](https://bl.ocks.org/kerryrodden/766f8f6d31f645c39f488a0befa1e3c8) [cool](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3231298) [library](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1345853)).

Comment: I really like the solution here. But I can't grasp one thing, is d3.select selecting the virtual dom element? Hence, leaving the dom update to React?

Comment: @Ege Naw, `axis` in this example is a real DOM element, not a virtual DOM element.  React reconciles the DOM and virtual DOM, then passes the real DOM element to the ref function.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response - then, that means, we are leaving manipulation of DOM to D3. I was trying to find a way to have React does it, but I got stuck at calling axisCreator function on selected SVG group (<g>) element. Have you found a way to achieve that before?

Comment: By the way, your solution here works like charm. I used it already - thank you! I am just trying to see the difference when react does it?.

Comment: @Ege Do you have a Fiddle/Sandbox/Codepen with your attempts to do it through React instead of d3?  It'd help if I could see it.

Comment: Sure, you can see the sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-lumiere-hkevr?file=/src/charts/d3-area-chart.jsx
What I want to do is not to use d3.select() but tell react to apply axis creator on <g> element. See `line 147` uses your example here. I want to do `d3.select('g')...call(xAxisCreator)` in React way and have React handle DOM manipulation. But I couldn't achieve it.

Comment: You labeled the use of refs as an anti-pattern, but it's not; in fact, ["Integrating with third-party DOM libraries." is one of the specific use cases of refs given in the React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#when-to-use-refs).  They do say "Avoid using refs for anything that can be done declaratively," but with the current d3 API, it can't be done declaratively.

Comment: Hmm, I see your point. I know the docs. The reason I labeled it as anti-pattern is that D3 handles the dom manipulation there instead of making the changes on virtual dom and let react do the updates. Is my thinking wrong?

Comment: I know there is a great tool [faux dom](https://github.com/Olical/react-faux-dom) where you can make the dom updates on the state and let react do the real update. But I just wanted to know how you would handle it bc you stated that you have years of experience solving this problem.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer! It helped me to solve the problem! However, I do not understand how it works. Before I had been using refs only with `React.createRef()`. However, here it seems you create ref by defining a custom method. I would highly appreciate if you could point me to where I could read more about it and understand how it works.

Comment: @desa You could just as well do it using `createRef` and then using the ref in both `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`, but I prefer using [a callback ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs) because it's simpler.

Comment: @Ege I've never used the faux DOM you referenced, so I don't know the pros and cons.  I was content with the ref once I found the line in the docs saying that this way an appropriate use of refs.

Comment: The callback ref is a nice "trick"! It plays nice with fast refresh too.

Answer (score 0):

The code for rendering axis using React directly, rather than d3's select API, is actually not that complex.  [react-d3-axis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-d3-axis) provides a pretty simple, [~100 loc](https://github.com/shauns/react-d3-axis/blob/master/src/Axis.js) implementation.  Going this approach lets you use d3 for stuff like data transformations and scale interpolation, and use React for rendering.